# How do I use brew to install an older version of ocaml?

Tags: macos, ocaml, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I'm using Mac OS Big Sur (11.5.6).  I want to install an older version of an ocaml library via brew (4.08.1).  I tried to figure out the versions available and typed

```
$ brew versions ocaml
Error: Unknown command: versions
```

and then following a recommended link, tried

```
localhost:Formula davea$ brew tap homebrew/boneyard
==> Tapping homebrew/boneyard
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-boneyard'...
Username for 'https://github.com': myusername
Password for 'https://myusername@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard/' not found
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-boneyard --origin=origin --template=` exited with 128.
```

Now I'm stuck.  How do I install an older version of my library, ocaml via brew?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for managing OCaml versions is probably to install opam, and then use it to install specific versions.

[How to install opam.](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html#macOS)